# Why does deleting the root node keep the left subtrees but not my right subtrees?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

So I have created a delete function for my BST implementation. It works properly for cases of deleting leaf nodes, and subtrees with a right child, but no left child and vice versa.

However, deleting the root node is giving me problems. I am trying to replace the root with its successor, and then set new root's right child equal to the old root's right child.

Example:

```
        50
       /  \
      /    \
     42     63
    / \    /
   /   \  55 
  21   43      
    \    \    
    23    \    
   / \    47
  /   \
 44   48
```

If I were to delete node 50 in my program, 55 would be the new root, but then 63 would just disappear, but everything else works fine.

Am I relinking the nodes wrong?
(Starts at **"Problem is Here"** comment in code)

```
//How I display my tree
//inprder traversal
private void inOrder(Node curr){

      if(curr != null){
         //traverse left
         inOrder(curr.leftChild);

         System.out.print("\n" + curr + "->");

         //traverse right
         inOrder(curr.rightChild);
      }

   } 

public boolean deleteContact(String key){
      //Start at root node
      Node currentNode = root;
      Node parent = root;

      boolean isLeftChld = true;
      //loop over left and right subtrees
      //finds node to be deleted
      while(!key.equals(currentNode.key)){

         parent = currentNode;

         if(key.compareToIgnoreCase(currentNode.key) < 0){

            isLeftChld = true;
            currentNode = currentNode.leftChild;

         }else{

            isLeftChld = false;
            currentNode = currentNode.rightChild;

         }
         //Node never found
         if(currentNode == null){
            return false;
         }
      }

      //if the node doesnt have children
      //go ahead and delete
      if(currentNode.leftChild == null && currentNode.rightChild == null){
         if(currentNode == root){

            root = null;
         //Handle case of juss deleting leafs
         }else if(isLeftChld){//check if it was a left or right child
            //delete it
            parent.leftChild = null;

         }else{

            parent.rightChild = null;

         }

      //situation of no right child
      //handling node dissapearing
      } else if(currentNode.rightChild == null){
         if(currentNode == root){

            root = currentNode.leftChild;
         }else if (isLeftChld){

            parent.leftChild = currentNode.leftChild;

         }else{

            parent.rightChild = currentNode.leftChild;
         }

      //situation of no left child
      }else if(currentNode.leftChild == null){
         if(currentNode == root){

            root = currentNode.rightChild;

         }else if (isLeftChld){

            parent.leftChild = currentNode.rightChild;

         }else{

            parent.rightChild = currentNode.leftChild;
         }
       **Problem is Here**
      //situation of two children being involved
      //figure out which node will replace which
      } else {
         //Node temp = currentNode.rightChild;
         Node successor = minValue(currentNode.rightChild);

         if(currentNode == root){
            root = successor;

         }else if(isLeftChld){
            parent.leftChild = successor;

         }else{
            parent.rightChild = successor;
         }

         root.leftChild = currentNode.leftChild;

      }

      return true;

   }

   //Function to return min value for a root node
   //Used for delete function - finds succesor
   private Node minValue(Node root)
    {
        Node minv = root;
        while (root.leftChild != null)
        {
            minv = root.leftChild;
            root = root.leftChild;
        }
        return minv;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the right child as well.

```
     //Root is 50 [42, 63]

     if(currentNode == root){
        root = successor;

     //Root is 55 [null, null]
     }else if(isLeftChld){
        parent.leftChild = successor;

     }else{
        parent.rightChild = successor;
     }

     //Root is 55 [42, null]
     root.leftChild = currentNode.leftChild;
```

The following line is missing:

```
     root.rightChild = currentNode.rightChild;
```

Comment: That what I thought. I did this initially, however, I get a stack overflow error. I know the error is a result of the recursion in my inOrder print function. But I am not sure why or how to fix it.

Comment: Oh! Also remember to set the parent of 55 to null. 63 points to left child 55 points to right child 63 in an infinite loop.

Comment: You can just copy the successor value to root and delete it as it doesn't have two children.

Comment: @ mani deepak When I set the successor value to null, it has no effect. I guess I still don't see the infinite loop @Compass was talking about.

Comment: Check the child of 63. When you move 55 to root, the left child of 63 should become null.